# How do I setup a systemwide hook to listen for WM_DEVICECHANGE?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hook

I want to setup a System wide hook to listen for `WM_DEVICECHANGE` in C++. I know that hooks are setup using `SetWindowsHookEx()`. I have done this before for Keyboard messages (`WM_KEYUP`, `WM_KEYDOWN`) but I want to do it for `WM_DEVICECHANGE`. I am currently using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
void WinHook();
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   WinHook();
   std::cout << GetLastError() << " winhook\n";
   return 0;
}

void WinHook()
{
   HHOOK hook = NULL;
   hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_GETMESSAGE, HookProc, NULL, GetCurrentThreadId());
   std::cout << GetLastError() << " sethook\n";
   MSG msg;
   while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
   {
      TranslateMessage(&msg);
      DispatchMessage(&msg);
   }
}
LRESULT CALLBACK HookProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
   std::cout << GetLastError() << " hookproc called\n";
   switch (wParam){
     case WM_DEVICECHANGE: std::cout << "SUCCESS!!!!!"; break;
     default: return CallNextHookEx(NULL, nCode, wParam, lParam);
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
The `GetLasterror()` after `SetWindowsHookEx()` returns 0, and the one in the function `HookProc()` is never called.

Comment: That message is sent to all top level windows, why hook? You can use RegisterDeviceNotification() and a hidden window

Comment: @AlexK. I don't want to use a hidden window, it is unnecessary.

Comment: Personally I would say installing a system wide hook is unnecessary if there is an alternative

Comment: You're using that actual code? I can see why it's not working for you; if it won't compile, it can't possibly execute, and if it can't execute it can't possibly catch the message. If you want us to help you figure out why your code isn't working, **post your actual code** and not something you made up on the fly when writing your question.

Comment: @KenWhite It is not made up. I have not posted the main method, that's it.

Comment: @KenWhite And the includes.

Comment: It's not the missing `main()` or the missing includes. The code you posted will not compile even with them; there is a clear error in the code. Read my last comment again, and then read [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @KenWhite Ok yes, I forgot to copy the message pump and I had to go away from my computer and I copied a message loop off the internet and I did not notice the `hwnd`. I just noticed it. I'll be able to edit it in 5 minutes. Till then if you know the solution please add an answer.

Comment: So you "copied a message loop off the internet", which means you **did not post your actual code**. Once again, if you want help solving a problem with **your code**, **post your actual code**.

Comment: You are building a DLL (library) for your hook, right? From the docs for [SetWIndowsHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): *All global hook functions must be in libraries. Global hooks should be restricted to special-purpose applications or to use as a development aid during application debugging.* An example of how to load the hook from the DLL is in [Installing and Releasing Hook Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960(v=vs.85).aspx#installing_releasing). Your code does none of the proper things.

Comment: lpfn [in]
Type: HOOKPROC
A pointer to the hook procedure. If the dwThreadId parameter is zero or specifies the identifier of a thread created by a different process, the lpfn parameter must point to a hook procedure in a DLL. **Otherwise, lpfn can point to a hook procedure in the code associated with the current process.** And no I am not creating a DLL. The code is from an executable.

Comment: **All global hook functions must be in libraries.** This is stated very clearly in the documentation. If it's in an executable, it can't be installed as a global hook. **Read the documentation I linked - it comes straight from Microsoft.** The part you bolded is relevant for local (thread) hooks, **not global hooks**. Your question asks about a **global hook**.

Comment: @KenWhite Would this not be a [better explaination](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/666b5e13-cad8-44ea-ad92-fb5c6670d110/how-do-i-setup-a-system-wide-hook-to-listen-for-wmdevicechange?forum=vcgeneral)

Comment: I give up. It's clear that you're not going to listen. Good luck.

Comment: As an aside, your error checking is wrong. Don't call GetLastError unless the function fails. The documentation explains this.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the function does not fail, `GetLastError()` will return 0.

Comment: Not necessarily. You need to do it the way I said, as stated in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are installing a WindowsHook for all messages that your own thread is receiving.

Your program does not open any window, it does not get any messages. So the hook will not be called.

As said in one of the comments you need to create a (maybe hidden) top level window and `RegisterDeviceNotification`, you don't need a hook.

Another way would be to install a system wide hook, but that requires an extra DLL and any other top level window on the desktop, and it is more complicated and more resource consuming.

Comment: There is no need to make a system wide hook in a DLL, I have code that works fine with the `HookProc()` in the same executable. But that code listens for WM_KEYUP.

Comment: @NabeelOmer, "`DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL` and `DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` events are automatically broadcast to all top-level windows for port devices.... Volume notifications are also broadcast to top-level windows". You need to create a window to see these messages. If you want specific device change messages, you'll need to register to receive them.

Comment: Just because the code works for keyboard hooks does not mean it is the right code to use for other hooks. Read the documentation. Your code is creating a **thread-specific** hook for the calling thread only. Your thread has a message loop, but has no windows to catch messages with. That is not the correct way to create a **global** message hook. You *must* implement the hook in a DLL so it can be injected into other processes, and you *must* set the `dwThreadId` parameter to 0 to hook all threads.

Answer (score 1):

It is a mistake to attempt to use a hook for this.

The correct approach is to use a window to receive the message. Perhaps a top level window if you have one at hand. Or a message only window. Top level windows will receive basic notifications. Or use [`RegisterDeviceNotification`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363431.aspx) with a message only window to receive more comprehensive notifications.